# create a if statement where only one button at a time can have a border

Tags: swift, if-statement, border, subtraction

I want my swift code to use a if statement or another sequence to only display a border on one of the buttons if click at a time. So a border can only be seen on one button at a time that button would be the last one pressed. I know I could say layer.border with 0 on each button that should be selected but I want to see if there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var ba = UIButton()
    var bb = UIButton()
    var bc = UIButton()
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [ba,bb,bc].forEach {
            
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        ba.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        bb.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        bc.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        
        ba.backgroundColor = .blue
        bb.backgroundColor = .orange
        bc.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        ba.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressa), for: .touchDown)
        bb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressb), for: .touchDown)
        bc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressc), for: .touchDown)
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func pressa(){
        ba.layer.borderWidth = 2
        
    }
    @objc func pressb(){
        bb.layer.borderWidth = 2
      }
    @objc func pressc(){
          bc.layer.borderWidth = 2
      }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add target to all buttons at the forEach and be only one method as @Sh_Khan mention

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var ba = UIButton()
    var bb = UIButton()
    var bc = UIButton()
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [ba,bb,bc].forEach {
            
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
      $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressAll(_:)), for: .touchDown)
        }
        ba.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        bb.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        bc.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        
        ba.backgroundColor = .blue
        bb.backgroundColor = .orange
        bc.backgroundColor = .darkGray 
    }
    
  @objc func pressAll(_ sender:UIButton) {
    [ba,bb,bc].forEach { $0.layer.borderWidth = 0 } // reset all
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 2 
}
   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be 1 method like this

```
  [ba,bb,bc].forEach { $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressAll(_:)), for: .touchDown) } 
}

@objc func pressAll(_ sender:UIButton) {
    [ba,bb,bc].forEach { $0.layer.borderWidth = 0 } // reset all
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 2 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See how you have used an array in `[ba,bb,bc].forEach { ... }` to reduce code duplication? Using arrays is the key. Rather than putting the three buttons in an array inline like that, create a property instead:

```
var buttons: [UIButton]!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttons = [ba,bb,bc]
    buttons.forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview($0)
        $0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchDown)
    }
    ...
}
```

I have used the same selector `buttonPressed` for all three buttons. `buttonPressed` can accept a parameter of type `UIButton`, that tells us which button is pressed:

```
@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    buttons.forEach { ba.layer.borderWidth = 0 } // deselect all buttons first...
    sender.layer.borderWidth = 2 // select the tapped button
}
```

---

If you have more than 3 buttons to manage, I suggest you don't use `UIButton`s at all. You should use a [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview). ([Learn how to use them](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started)) This view will handle the selection for you. It also allows scrolling when there's not enough space to show all the buttons. You just need to create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and override its `isSelected` property:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 2
        } else {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }
    }
}
```